# Add message to queue when CRUD operation is executed on my database

Tags: c#, database, entity-framework, dbcontext

**Background**

I have a MVC website with a Entity Framework code first database (main database). I also have a reporting database which will feed data to my reporting pages. Further I have a queue where I can add a message and a service will pick it up and sync data between the main database and the reporting database.

Note that the database don't have the same schema.

**Problem**

I would like to add a message to my queue (so I can sync data between my databases) **after** the database operation has finished and the records have been inserted/updated/deleted.

**Ideas**

I was thinking to overwrite DbContext's SaveChanges() method and call my method to insert a message to the queue but I'm not sure this is a good idea. Any thoughts?

Or a SQL trigger that adds a message to the queue? (I don't really like this idea as I don't want to my any business logic to SQL).

Comment: Do you want your databases to be replicates? Or you want different data in your databases?

Comment: I basically want to copy some data (not all) from my main database to my reporting database. The two databases have different schema.

Comment: Why would you not use an ETL process and use something like SSIS?

Comment: @Macilquham I would like to keep my business logic, i.e. determine which database records to sync from my main database to my reporting database, in my code and not having this in SQL. Is that possible with the approach you suggest?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it within EF you could look at DbCommandInterceptor http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/entityframework6/database-command-interception.aspx

I would also suggest looking at SSIS, I know you want to do this all in code but SSIS is purpose built for data migration. I am no SSIS expert but I know you can both call web services (web service task) https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms140114.aspx and also execute .net code (script task) https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms135944.aspx

Agreed having too much business logic in sql can be a bad thing but if the alternative is building complex migration code then obviously you need to weigh up and pros and cons.

The last thing ill mention is http://tsqlt.org/ unit tests at the database level, which can help overcome some of the drawbacks of having business logic stored in the db.

HTH